# Spark job and optimization

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a spark job with code as below

```
def call_stripes(rdd,voc,bas):
    vocabulary =sc.broadcast(voc)
    basis=sc.broadcast(bas)
    def create_stripes(words):
        vocab=set()
        basis=set()
        basis_set = set(words).intersection(basis.value)
        vocab_set = set(words).intersection(vocabulary.value)

        for key in list(vocab_set):
            basis_nokey = set(basis_set)
            #if key and value are same, just discard
            basis_nokey.discard(key)
            if basis_nokey != set():
                yield (key, basis_nokey)

    
    result = rdd.map(lambda line: (line.lower().split('\t')[0].split())) \
                .flatMap(create_stripes) \
                .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x|y) 
    return result

stripesrdd=call_stripes(rdd,voc,bas)

print(stripesrdd.top(5))
```

I get data in format "some space separated text"\t1\t1 initially. I am interested only in the text so the map will take care of sending text into flatMap(createStripes).

if you look at that function, there are two data sources vocabulary and basis which are broadcasted data. vocabulary contains full vocabulary and basis contains a subset of vocabulary. The idea is to create a spark job which creates stripes.

if the any of the given words exist in vocabulary, they become keys of a set. if the word exists in basis that becomes a value. I need to create a list of such items. ie [(word1, {et, boo}), (word2, {dex, mine, buy})]. Call to top(5) is taking 60+sec. From spark ui i see that reducebykey is the one where time is spent

I have trouble with this 1) its giving me different data than expected 2) its taking too long ie around 60+ sec but it should take around 1.5+sec!!! Appreciate any insights on where I am going wrong and what optimizations can i do will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the broadcasted variable value through a local variable and the performance increased.